# Realm init for storyboard tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I'm having a problem implementing a synced realm with a storyboard ViewController.

Specifically I'm unsure how to provide the initializers.

If I create the ViewController programmatically I can use the following and everything works fine. However, I'm working with a storyboard. *This code is provided by the realm tutorial.*

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ItemsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let realm: Realm
let items: Results<Item>

let refresh = UIRefreshControl()

let tableView = UITableView()
var notificationToken: NotificationToken?

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    let syncConfig = SyncConfiguration(user: SyncUser.current!, realmURL: Constants.REALM_URL)
    self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: syncConfig, objectTypes:[Item.self]))
    self.items = realm.objects(Item.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "body", ascending: true)

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

deinit {
    notificationToken?.invalidate()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Items to Get Done"
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.frame = self.view.frame

....
```

This does not work for a storyboard ViewConroller since (as I understand) the storyboard is configuring and initializing the ViewConroller.

My question then is, how and where do I write the init?

Answer (score 1):

You can write realm loading in your ViewDidLoad.

```
        import UIKit
        import RealmSwift

        class ItemTableViewController: UITableViewController {

            var realm!
            var items: Results<Item>?

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                self.loadItems()
            }


            //Readcategory:
            func loadItems() {
                let syncConfig = SyncConfiguration(user: SyncUser.current!, realmURL: Constants.REALM_URL)
                self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: syncConfig, objectTypes:[Item.self]))
                self.items = realm.objects(Item.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "body", ascending: true)
                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            }

            // MARK: - Table view data source
            override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return self.items?.count
            }

            override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! SwipeCell
                if let item = self.items?[indexPath.row] {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title

                }
                return cell
            }
        }
```

Comment: That code does not appear to work. It doest not satisfy the requirement for the view controller to have an initializer, as I still get the error. "Class 'ItemViewController' has no initializers".

Comment: Y do u need a initializer to a viewcontroller if u r instatiating viewcontroller from a storyboard

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why I keep getting this error.

Comment: Y do you think you need to write a initializer and call seperatly for this purpose?

Comment: The error that I am getting is.  Class 'mainViewConroller' has no initializers.